# Margin for Two Boxes Isn't Correct

Tags: c#, wpf, margins

so I have two boxes, and the goal here is to have both boxes have the exact same margins from the edge of the window. Unfortunately, in WPF, you only get the margin from the left side, and not both, so to make sure of that, I have the following formula;

> The margin of the second box is equal to the window width minus the margin of the first box minus the size of the box.

And this can be backed up with math, it *does* work. And so I did get my program to figure this out, since it's reactive. And so now I have this image:

WPF Window
[image]

The text in the middle is to prove that this calculation is correct. (just so you know, each box is 500px wide) So, the first number is the margin of the first box. The second is the margin of the second, and the last is the window size. Do the math and you have this equation:

> (1936 - 88) - 500 = 1348

And that does work, however, if you look in the image, the box on the right is just a little bit closer to the edge than the one on the left. This happens too if you resize it, it's not just when maximized. What's up, and how can I fix this?

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="Horizon_Chat.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Horizon_Chat"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:Horizon_Chat"
        i:WindowEx.ShowIcon = "false"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Horizon Chat" Height="900" Width="1280" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" MinWidth="600" MinHeight="600" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="welcomeTitleText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-200,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello Camden!" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Muli" FontSize="60"/>
        <Border x:Name="topBorder" BorderBrush="#FF646464" BorderThickness="0,0,0,4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1273" Margin="0,32,0,0"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="#FF30B44E" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" StrokeThickness="3"/>
        <Border x:Name="chatsBox" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" Margin="58,594,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500"/>
        <Border x:Name="friendsBox" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" Margin="724,594,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You might be better off using a `Grid` to space them out

Comment: Please show your XAML. I never had a problem defining the margins.

Comment: @gdir I added it.

Comment: @User1178 I suggest that you read about layout panels in WPF. Choosing the right layout panel makes WPF very easy. Trying to set margins like in WinForms isn't the right way. [WPF layout panels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview)

Comment: If 1936 is the window's Width, be aware that it includes (twice) the width of the window's border. Note that you could easily set the right margin and HorizontalAlignment to Right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a grid, set the `ColumnDefinition` `Widths` to your rectangle width + the margin you want. The * used for the middle `Column`'s `Width` means "Fill up the available space". The `Margin` parameter is set up as (Left, Top, Right, Bottom). This allows you to specify a right hand `Margin`.

```
<Window x:Class="ForStackoverflow.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ForStackoverflow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Margin="15 0 0 0" 
                   StrokeThickness="5" 
                   Stroke="Black"
                   Height="80"
                   Grid.Column="0"/>

        <Rectangle Margin="0 0 15 0" 
                   StrokeThickness="5" 
                   Stroke="Black"
                   Height="80"
                   Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```